# How to select next date from table in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have table containing following info

```
Quarter_END_DATE | Flag 
2014/31/03       |  N 
2014/30/06       |  Y 
2014/30/09       |  N 
2014/31/12       |  N
```

and so on....

whenever query will be run it should update the next quarter `flag to Y` and `previous to N`

Please provide the solution to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Update next quarter's flag to `Y` (assume there is only one `Y` flag in the table):

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET Flag = 'Y'
WHERE Quarter_END_DATE = DATEADD(day, 90, (
   SELECT FIRST(Quarter_END_DATE)
   FROM [table_name]
   WHERE Flag = 'Y'));
```

update previous quarter's flag to `N`:

```
UPDATE [table_name] SET Flag = 'N'
WHERE Quarter_END_DATE = (
   SELECT MIN(Quarter_END_DATE)
   FROM [table_name]
   WHERE Flag = 'Y'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tab
FROM 
 ( SELECT Quarter_END_DATE, Flag
   FROM tab
   QUALIFY Flag = 'Y'   -- current row with 'Y'
        OR MAX(Flag)    -- next row to be set to 'Y'
           OVER (ORDER BY Quarter_END_DATE
                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND  1 PRECEDING) = 'Y'
 ) AS src
SET Flag = CASE WHEN src.Flag = 'Y' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END -- switch the flag
WHERE tab.Quarter_END_DATE = src.Quarter_END_DATE
  AND tab.Flag = src.Flag
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to state what dbms you are operating off of, however if you were doing this in mysql you could:

```
update [table_name] set flag = 'N'
where flag = 'Y'
;

update [table_name] set flag = 'Y'
where quarter_end_date between now() and dateadd(now(), 90 DAYS);
```